# Get MYSQL results iterate through them and add new values to DB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, function

I am still learning vb.net and i need to create function to get results from mysql, multiply value and then add those values to database.

This is what i've done till now:

```
Public Sub updateusers()
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='1'"
    CONNECTION.Open()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Userpanellistview.Items.Clear()

    Do While dr.Read()
        valx = (dr.Item("userid").ToString())
        valy = (dr.Item("value").ToString())
        valz = (dr.Item("value").ToString) * (dr.Item("plusvalue").ToString())



        Dim list As ListViewItem = Userpanellistview.Items.Add(a)
        list.SubItems.Add(valx)
        list.SubItems.Add(valy)
        list.SubItems.Add(valz)
    Loop
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    CONNECTION.Close()
End Sub
```

I need to update values for "user" table with command:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE users SET status=2, calcammount='" & valz & "' WHERE userid='" & valx & "'"
```

Now, i don't know where to start, should I make another function and pass values from this function updateusers or can I just put code here in this function to update every row as it pulls it from database?

Comment: Frist of all, google for " parametrized query". Your question is not clear. The query you wrote is correct, You need to loop the list and run an update query for each user.

Comment: Here is simple question: Can i use another query inside this function to update table?

Comment: of course you can, as jmcilhinney  said, the best way is to use a datatable, fill it with your query and send it back to the database ( ADO.NET ). If you still need the list, to display some data back to the user, fill it with the datatable.

And anyway, my tip is to create a function for each operation, this help keep code clean.
I renew the tip to google for " parametrized query "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a data reader if you want to save data.  Either do it all in SQL and call ExecuteNonQuery to execute an appropriate UPDATE statement or use a data adapter.  In the latter case, call Fill to populate a DataTable with the desired data, loop through the Rows of that DataTable and make the appropriate modifications and then call Update on the same adapter to save the changes back to the database.  You'll need to populate at least the UpdateCommand of the data adapter if you want to modify existing rows, which you can do manually or using a command builder.